# You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "tabs" error in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have defined a watcher on tabs just to prevent the tabs from changing based on the values of the edit. if edit is false then go to next tab else prevent. But when I click on the tab heading to change the tab I am getting this. changes_event and changes_cancel are custom events sent to parent from child component.

*You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "tabs" error*. Please help me figureout where I am going wrong.

```html
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12>
      <div>
        <v-tabs v-model="tabs">
          <v-tab href="#information">INFORMATION</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#details">DETAILS</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#services">SERVICES</v-tab>
          <v-tab-item value="#information" v-on:changes_event="alertMessage" v-on:changes_cancel="alertPhone" id="information">
            <Information />
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#details" v-on:changes_event="alertMessage" v-on:changes_cancel="alertPhone" id="details">
            <Details />
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#services" v-on:changes_event="alertMessage" v-on:changes_cancel="alertPhone" id="services">
            <Services />
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

```js
import Information from 'views/information/edit.vue';
import Details from 'views/details/edit.vue';
import Services from 'views/services/edit.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Information,
    Details,
    Services,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      tabs: 'information',
      edit: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    tabs(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (this.edit) {
        this.tabs = oldVal
      } else {
        this.tabs = newVal
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    alertMessage() {
      this.edit = true;
    },
    alertPhone() {
      this.edit = false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For example**, assuming the initial value for `this.tabs='1'`, if `this.edit` is true, and let `this.tabs='11'`, so the newVal of the watch will be `'11'`, and oldVal of the watch will be `'1'`; then `this.tabs` will be changed to `this.tabs='1'` because of `this.edit` is true. now `newVal='1', oldVal='11'`, finally it will fall into one infinite loop.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
      return {
        tabs: '1',
        edit: true
      }
  },
  watch: {
    tabs: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log(newVal, oldVal)
      if (this.edit) this.tabs = oldVal
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="A" v-model="tabs">
        </div>
        <pre>{{tabs}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

**One workaround** is uses the setter of one computed property.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
      return {
        tabs: '1',
        edit: true,
        tabsCopy: this.tabs
      }
  },
  computed: {
    myTabs: {
      get: function () {
        return this.tabs
      },
      set: function (newVal) {
        if (this.edit) {
          this.$forceUpdate()
          return
        }
        this.tabs= newVal
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="edit">
            <input type="text" v-model="myTabs">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Another solution** is perform the validation in @input.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
      return {
        tabs: '1',
        edit: true,
        tabsCopy: this.tabs
      }
  },
  methods: {
    changeValue: function (newVal) {
      if(this.edit) { this.$forceUpdate(); return}
      this.tabs = newVal.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="edit">
            <input type="text" :value="tabs" @input="changeValue($event)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The worse workaround** is uses one data property to check if newVal matches it, if yes, return immediately.

Anyway, it is not a good idea to use one watch to determinate its watch object if need to be changed or not.

So uses **the solution setter of computed property** will be better.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue ({
  el:'#app',
  data () {
      return {
        tabs: '1',
        edit: true,
        tabsCopy: this.tabs
      }
  },
  watch: {
    tabs: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal == this.tabsCopy) return
      if (this.edit) {
        this.tabs = oldVal
        this.tabsCopy = this.tabs
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="edit">
            <input type="text" v-model="tabs">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```